# Could not load file or assembly 'aacorlib' Error in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I have just deployed an asp.net application in IIS with asp.net version 4.0 and Application pool mode Integrated. I am getting below error when I hit the application URL for the first time. Then the Published Code runs fine.

I have tried deleting temp asp.net files and resetting IIS several times.

Error:

`Could not load file or assembly 'aacorlib, Version=0.5.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc0e3af5abcb6c4' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified`.

Error Location:

```
Line 74:     <asp:ScriptManager ID="smLogin" runat="server">
Line 75:     </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: 32bit and 64bit issue? .Net Framework version issue?

Comment: All of our enviorment is 64 Bit, Frame work is 4.0

Answer (score 1):

You can try marking the project reference to aacorlib with "copylocal"; you may need to add assembly binding to your config.